# UI won't change in real time w/ CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI + CoreData simple Todo app, and everything works properly, but my updateTodo function which is supposed to handle the click on a todo and turn in from done to undone and vice versa, isn't working properly.
When I click on a todo nothing happens in the UI, but when I go a screen back and come back to the todos screen, I can see the UI change, also it does persist so when I close and open the app the change is being reflected in the app.
So my problem is that the 'isDone' property is not being toggled in the UI in real-time, and only when the view reappears it actually shows the change that has been made.

ViewModel (CoreData) :

```
class TodoViewModel:ObservableObject {
    
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    @Published var categories = [CategoryTodo]()
    @Published var todos = [Todo]()
    
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "UniversityProject")
        container.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: - Todos
    func getTodos() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Todo>(entityName: "Todo")
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Todo.dateCreated), ascending: false)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        do {
            try todos = container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("Error getting data. \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    
    func addTodo(todo text: String, category categoryName:String) {
        let newTodo = Todo(context: container.viewContext)
        newTodo.todo = text
        newTodo.category = categoryName
        newTodo.id = UUID().uuidString
        newTodo.isDone = false
        newTodo.dateCreated = Date()
        saveTodo()
    }
    
    func saveTodo() {
        do {
            try container.viewContext.save()
            getTodos()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func deleteTodo(indexSet: IndexSet) {
        let todoIndex = indexSet[indexSet.startIndex]
        let object = todos[todoIndex]
        container.viewContext.delete(object)
        saveTodo()
    }
    
    func updateTodo(item: Todo) {
            item.setValue(!item.isDone, forKey: "isDone")
            saveTodo()
    }
    
}
```

TodosView:

```
struct TodosView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: TodoViewModel
    
    let categoryName:String
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.todos.filter{$0.category == categoryName}) { item in
                TodoItem(item: item)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.linear) {
                            viewModel.updateTodo(item: item)
                        }
                    }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: viewModel.deleteTodo)
            
        }.onAppear { viewModel.getTodos() }
        
            .navigationBarTitle(categoryName)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    HStack {
                        EditButton()
                        NavigationLink(destination: AddTodoView(category: categoryName)) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                                .resizable()
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

without all relevent code, I can only guess and suggest you try something like these:

```
func updateTodo(item: Todo) {
    if let ndx = todos.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == item.id}) {
        todos[ndx].isDone = !item.isDone
        saveTodo()
    }
}
```

or

```
func updateTodo(item: Todo) {
    objectWillChange.send()
    item.setValue(!item.isDone, forKey: "isDone")
    saveTodo()
}
```

Comment: More code is necessary ? I’ll gladly post more code I’m just not sure if there’s any more code that’ll be relevant to the issue

Comment: There are a number of missing parts, and without a `minimal, reproducible example` (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is difficult to test any answer. I take it that my `updateTodos` code did not work for you.

Comment: I will create one then, also it didn't work, the behaviour didn't change.